# Displaying results from 3 different For loops into a table

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to display all three lists side by side with the names associated with the values in a table format. I am manually doing it right now and it's taking a while for all 20 files I must do. Thank you for your help!

```
  maxpreandpost = [Pre1,Pre2,Pre3,Pre4,Pre5,Pre6,Pre7,Pre8,Pre9,Pre10,Post1,Post2,Post3,Post4,Post5,Post6,Post7,Post8,Post9,Post10]
    for i in maxpreandpost:
        height = max(i.Z)
        print (height)
```

165.387
160.214
159.118
186.685
163.744
160.717
184.026
171.25099999999995
175.73
156.512
150.339
131.528
148.52100000000004
126.738
136.389
148.334
129.855
153.599
144.595
159.32299999999995

```
lenpreandpost = [Pre1,Pre2,Pre3,Pre4,Pre5,Pre6,Pre7,Pre8,Pre9,Pre10,Post1,Post2,Post3,Post4,Post5,Post6,Post7,Post8,Post9,Post10]
for i in lenpreandpost:
    duration = len(i.Z)
    print (duration)
```

690
543
292
271
293
147
209
355
230
293
395
256
349
255
335
255
231
243
315
267

```
dis = [Pre1,Pre2,Pre3,Pre4,Pre5,Pre6,Pre7,Pre8,Pre9,Pre10,Post1,Post2,Post3,Post4,Post5,Post6,Post7,Post8,Post9,Post10]
for i in dis:
    p1 = [max(i.X),max(i.Y)]
    p2 = [min(i.X),min(i.Y)]
    distance = math.sqrt(((p1[0]-p2[0])**2)+((p1[1]-p2[1])**2)) 
    print (distance)
```

2219.0546989150585
2337.434842606099
1857.1832474809803
1450.0472277998394
1512.6539831504758
1058.5635689541748
1653.517987682021
1854.670452561212
1861.8190476064021
1775.672511965326
1872.275393720069
1814.9932559772114
1852.3299779009246
1875.2281201398403
1867.1599096301313
1708.250531327712
1793.8521780715407
1862.7949271803914
1872.843665022548
1800.2239125453254

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, append all values to output lists and then add them to a pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

heightmax = []
maxpreandpost = [Pre1,Pre2,Pre3,Pre4,Pre5,Pre6,Pre7,Pre8,Pre9,Pre10,Post1,Post2,Post3,Post4,Post5,Post6,Post7,Post8,Post9,Post10]
for i in maxpreandpost:
    height = max(i.Z)
    heightmax.append(height)

duration_pre_post = []
lenpreandpost = [Pre1,Pre2,Pre3,Pre4,Pre5,Pre6,Pre7,Pre8,Pre9,Pre10,Post1,Post2,Post3,Post4,Post5,Post6,Post7,Post8,Post9,Post10]
for i in lenpreandpost:
    duration = len(i.Z)
    duration_pre_post.append(duration)

dis_p1_p2 = []
dis = [Pre1,Pre2,Pre3,Pre4,Pre5,Pre6,Pre7,Pre8,Pre9,Pre10,Post1,Post2,Post3,Post4,Post5,Post6,Post7,Post8,Post9,Post10]
for i in dis:
    p1 = [max(i.X),max(i.Y)]
    p2 = [min(i.X),min(i.Y)]
    distance = math.sqrt(((p1[0]-p2[0])**2)+((p1[1]-p2[1])**2)) 
    dis_p1_p2.append(distance)

df = pd.DataFrame() # initialize empty dataframe

# Store each list as a column in the df.
df['HeightMax'] = heightmax
df['DurationPrePost'] = duration_pre_post
df['DistanceP1P2'] = dis_p1_p2

#if you want to write this out to a tabular file:

df.to_csv('./Desktop/myDf.csv', sep='\t', index=False)
```

The output of this would be something like:

```
  HeightMax    DurationPrePost    DistanceP1P2
0  165.387          690           2219.0546989150585
1  160.214          543           2337.434842606099
2  159.118          292           1857.1832474809803 
3  186.685          271           1450.0472277998394
4  163.744          293           1512.6539831504758
... #extends to end of lists
```